# Is that possible to make <video> mirrored?

Tags: html, css, video

Is that possible to make a video inside  tag mirrored horizontally or vertically?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can do it using a CSS3 3D transformation.

```
#videoElement
{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg); /* Firefox */
}
```

This will rotate it 180 degrees around its Y axis (so you're now looking at it from behind) which gives the same appearance as being mirrored.

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/DuT9U/1/

Comment: Rotating an object is different than mirroring it!

Comment: @Veger - if you rotate it 180 degrees, you've flipped it half-way-around, which means you're looking at it from behind. This gives the same appearance as being mirrored. You can rotateX(180deg) to give the appearance of being mirrored top-to-bottom as well. Try it yourself and see.

Comment: No... Flipping is like looking in a mirror, all x (or y) coordinates are swapped. Rotating it applying a more complex formula to all coordinates. Note: flipping horizontally *and* vertically is equal to rotating 180 degrees. (But this is 'coincidence'), See [this page](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~smx/IVIPracticals/exercise1.html) for a graphical comparison.

Comment: @Verger, if it gives the same appearance then any technicalities are irrelevant. And since the only other way to 'flip' something with CSS is by using a negative scale then it's pretty moot. It's all hardware accelerated so there's no performance difference either.

Comment: It does not show the same, as the OP wanted to just flip horizontally *or* vertically... Check the link again and carefully notice the differences...

Comment: Yes it does - rotating 180 degrees makes it look mirrored - http://jsfiddle.net/DuT9U/1/

Comment: Nice example! You are right, by applying `rotateX` and/or `rotateY` You are able to get a horizontal/vertical flip effect as well.

Comment: Same effect with 
`{
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform:scaleX(-1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scaleX(-1); /* Firefox */
}`

Comment: rotateY doesn't work on safari for video elements. You need to use scaleX(-1).

Comment: I've tried this suggestion (as well as the scaleX option mentioned in comments) and both work except when the video is maximized to full screen. Is there a solution that would also work when the video is in full-screen mode?

Comment: Any easy way to not mirror the video controls?

Comment: @webjay You'd have to disable them and then roll your own controls in a separate element to avoid them being flipped.

Comment: The downside of all these approaches is that your video controls get inverted as well.

Comment: @Yuri in that situation you disable the videos own controls, and implement your own.

Answer (score 17):

You can use CSS3 `scaleX` or `scaleY` set to -1 to respectively flip the video horizontally or vertically.

Answer (score 11):

Using JavaScript, if `video` is the video element, to mirror (flip horizontally) you can use

```
video.style.cssText = "-moz-transform: scale(-1, 1); \
-webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1); -o-transform: scale(-1, 1); \
transform: scale(-1, 1); filter: FlipH;";
```

To flip vertically you can use

```
video.style.cssText = "-moz-transform: scale(1, -1); \
-webkit-transform: scale(1, -1); -o-transform: scale(1, -1); \
transform: scale(1, -1); filter: FlipV;";
```

Comment: Interesting, does the flip inflict a performance penalty for video?

Comment: @MichaelIvanov In my experience I haven't really noticed performance penalties

Answer (score 6):

By any chance if somebody wants a working example, here is the code (with mirrored/rotated). Refer the video element #videoElement under style tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="stuff, to, help, search, engines, not" name="keywords">
<meta content="What this page is about." name="description">
<meta content="Display Webcam Stream" name="title">
<title>Display Webcam Stream</title>

<style>
#container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    border: 10px #333 solid;
}
#videoElement {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    background-color: #666;
    /*Mirror code starts*/
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg); /* Firefox */
    /*Mirror code ends*/
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">

    </video>
</div>
<script>
 var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

 navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

 if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
     navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
 }

 function handleVideo(stream) {
     video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
 }

 function videoError(e) {
     // do something
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

to prevent rotating controls

```
video {
  transform: scale(-1,1);
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
 transform: scale(-1,1);
  }
```

Comment: I could not manage to make it work for Firefox. Do you have a tip for this?