# Mirrored HTML 5 Video

Tags: html, css

I want to apply mirror effect on my HTML 5 Video. I did this by applying this CSS

```
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
  filter: FlipH;
```

It's working on desktop and web, but it's not working on mobiles (when we enter into full screen).

Comment: Unable to reproduce, when entering fullscreen "flipping" will not affect it anymore even on desktop: http://jsfiddle.net/4cwdzxv6/1/  The css only applies to the html-element which in fullscreen mode is not the case anymore.

Answer (score 2):

According to @PhonicUK in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455844/is-that-possible-to-make-video-mirrored)

here's the solution most used browsers:

```
#videoElement
{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg); /* Firefox */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rotateY property instead of scale for this:

```
transform:rotateY(180deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make it compatible for all web browsers. Try something like this:

```
-moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1); -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
transform: scale(-1, 1); filter: FlipH;
```

See filter property compatibilities: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Answer (score 0):

If you’re able to then you should flip the actual source video and save a new version rather than trying this in code. I don’t know what performance hit this has for mobiles and I think full screen mode is ‘outside’ the browser’s context and varies per device. If you can’t edit the source video then heopfully the other answer can help.