# Is there any HTML5 video javascript lib support mirror the video stream without flipping the control?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Is there any HTML5 video javascript lib support mirror the video stream without flipping the media control panel?

I know I can disable the native control and display my own control.

However, I don't want to build my own control.

I would be grateful if the example(s) is/are provided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is that possible to make <video> mirrored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455844/is-that-possible-to-make-video-mirrored) ... ah, this mirrors the controls, so you'd have to disable them and display your own

Comment: question updated.